# Where can I find missing GPO setting?

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy

Some of our clients have issues with the Sign In client for Exchange Online and I'm trying to follow this KB http://support.microsoft.com/kb/972654 but one of the settings I need to adjust isn't there.

Where can I find the setting below? There's a bunch of other "Network access"-settings, but just not this one:

```
Network access: Do not allow storage of credentials or .NET Passports for network authentication
```

(I'm using Windows 2008 R2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have it on a clean Server 2008 R2 build, either, which could be correct according to this Technet article:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779377(WS.10).aspx

I do, however, have:

> Network access: Do not allow storage of passwords and credentials for
>   network authentication

Which isn't listed there, so I wonder if it has replaced it.

Comment: It didn't solve the problem but it's probably the right setting. Thanks!